# "Covered in" or "Covered with" trash

Tags: grammar, prepositions, differences, phrasal-verbs

> The mountain is *covered in* trash
> The mountain is *covered with* trash

I find both of them correct but I can't say for sure. Is "covered in" or "covered with" more suitable in this context?

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand it, it comes down to a difference in meaning and implication.

- **The mountain is covered with trash**

This implies that the mountain is covered in so much trash, it's as if you put a blanket on top of it. You basically cannot see the mountain anymore because of the trash.

- **The mountain is covered in trash**

This implies that there is trash everywhere, but the mountain is still recognizable.